# JQuery datatables search by date in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I'm using JQuery datatables. In the first load of the page that has two datatables in it, there are almost 7000 rows to load and it takes so much time. What I'm trying to achieve is, placing two datepickers to load between specific dates so that it doesn't take so much time to load the page at first. However, I have a question in my mind: to use datatable's datepicker for filtering, do I still need to load the whole data at first page load? Or, when I change the dates, it will go to repository to start the LINQ that queries for the specific date?

Comment: What you require database queries or Jquery side search facilities ???

Answer (score 0):

If you use the datatable plugin (www.datatables.net).

You have a solution you can adapt here:

Query =>
    DataRow[] rows = newTable.Select("date >= #" + from_date + "# AND date <= #" + to_date + "#");

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html

http://www.thoughtdelimited.org/thoughts/demos/dataTablesDateRange/

I think you would need a column that shows a value for Value date or message date so that you can apply a filter, if not, javascript would not know how to filter.

Look at the line:

```
 oTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
```

The second value would be the index of the column where you have the values to be filtered.

Comment: I know I can apply that, but if this technique queries just what the datatable already has, it is not useful for me. I guess I should use a button to load the same view with two datepicker values and pass them to the ActionResult method and it should return the same view with different date values each time I change the date.